# В данных Get запроса во Flask принимает b''

Tags: python, flask, get

От api сервиса ко мне приходят данные такого типа:

?imya={object.user.first_name}&pochta={object.user.email}&telefon={object.user.phone}

Данные передаются прямо в url
В итоге мне приходит строка:   b''

Пробовал принимать данные в json, тогда приходит none

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/api", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    data = request.data
    datalist = open('/data.txt', 'a')
    datalist.write(str(data)+'\n')
    datalist.close()
    return str(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

Comment: `request.args` ..

Comment: Вау! Заработало! только вот почему то не видит сами данные, только заголовки:
ImmutableMultiDict([('imya', ''), ('pochta', ''), ('telefon', '')])
а присылаются: ImmutableMultiDict([(&#039;imya&#039;, &#039;&#039;), (&#039;pochta&#039;, &#039;&#039;), (&#039;telefon&#039;, &#039;&#039;)])